# To print the count of occurrences of a word ending with "on" in python

Tags: python, string, counting

```
my_string = """Strings are gameon amongst gameon the most popular data types in Python. We can create the strings by enclosing characters briton in quotes. Python treats briton single quotes the same as double quotes."""
def count_words(string):
    for word in string.split():
        if word.endswith("on") == True:
            print(word,":",string.count(word))
            string = string.replace(word,'')
count_words(my_string)
```

I want to print all the words and their occurences in a word if they end with "on". I am getting something like

```
gameon : 2
gameon : 0
briton : 2
Python : 2
briton : 0
```

this even after removing the word. 
Why it is repeating?

Edit: I can't use any module. Only logic.

Comment: Use a dictionary for storing strings and their count and don't delete items inside a loop.

Comment: It is 'repeating' because you count `gameon` each time you see the word  as you iterate (i.e. twice- first time there are 2, second time you've replaced them all with empty strings, so there are 0 in the string but the list remain uneffected of course)

Comment: You should use regex!! Also, strings are immutable. You can't loop over one and modify it as you're doing so. `string = string.replace(word,'')` just changes what the local variable `string` is, it doesn't change `my_string` itself... nor does it change the values you're iterating over using `for word in string.split()`, which is a (split up) copy of string itself.

Comment: Thankyou so much guys! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_string = """Strings are gameon amongst gameon the most popular data types in Python. We can create the strings by enclosing characters briton in quotes. Python treats briton single quotes the same as double quotes."""

di={}
def count_words(string):
    for word in string.split():
        if word.endswith("on") == True:
            if word in di:
                di[word]+=1
            else:
                di[word]=1
            string = string.replace(word,'')
            #print(string)
count_words(my_string)
for i in di:
    print(i,di[i])
```

You can use a dictionary to achieve the same.

Comment: But with this I am getting Python: 1

Comment: 1st Python ends with a `.` so it won't be counted.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to modify your string while you are counting.

Instead, you can use `collections.Counter` with a generator expression. It's also worth, as below, converting to lowercase and removing punctuation.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

table = str.maketrans(punctuation, ' ' * len(punctuation))
x = my_string.translate(table).lower()

c = Counter(i for i in x.split() if i.endswith('on'))

print(c)

Counter({'gameon': 2, 'python': 2, 'briton': 2})
```

Comment: They are not modifying the collection that they iterate over (a list) they are modifying the string, which effects the resulting counts of course

Comment: @Chris_Rands, Fair point, hve updated with more reasonable advice.

Comment: Modifying immutable strings and modifying sequences you're iterating over... very suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
import collections
my_string = """Strings are gameon amongst gameon the most popular data types in Python. We can create the strings by enclosing characters briton in quotes. Python treats briton single quotes the same as double quotes."""
def count_words(string):
    for word, v in collections.Counter(string.split()).items():
        if word.endswith("on"):
            print(word,":",v)        

count_words(my_string)
```

**Output:**

```
('Python', ':', 1)
('briton', ':', 2)
('gameon', ':', 2)
```

Comment: Why is it giving Python only once when it is present twice.

Comment: Because one of the 'python' ends with `.` --> `Python.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.Series` to `value_counts()` these words

```
from string import punctuation
my_string = ''.join(w for w in my_string if w not in set(punctuation))
pd.Series([i for i in my_string.split(" ") if i.endswith("on")]).value_counts()
>> (gameon, 2), (briton, 2), (Python, 2)
```